foreach Warning: Undefined array key
<?
$data[]['open'] = 1;
$data[]['close'] = 2;
$data[]['high'] = 3;
$data[]['low'] = 4;

$data[]['open'] = 5;
$data[]['close'] = 6;
$data[]['high'] = 7;
$data[]['low'] = 8;

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value['open'];
    }
?>

Результат работы:
1
Мая

Warning: Undefined array key "open" in … on line 14

Но если написать
…
foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        print_r($value);

        echo "<hr />";

    }

…
то выдает
Array ( [open] => 1 )

Array ( [close] => 2 )

Array ( [high] => 3 )

Array ( [low] => 4 )

Array ( [open] => 5 )

Array ( [close] => 6 )

Array ( [high] => 7 )

Array ( [low] => 8 )

Откуда в первом случае предупреждение и как его убрать, ну кроме директив к php

вы создали массив массивов. и в первом массиве индекс 'open' есть, а в других массивах - нет. скорее всего вам нужно просто линейный массив создать. Или сначала проверять isset($value['open'])

Точно.
Массив 2-х мерный должен быть. Я по аналогии с одномерным инициализацию сделал. Нужно индексы прописать.
$data['25.08.24']['open'] = 1;
$data['25.08.24']['close'] = 2;
$data['25.08.24']['high'] = 3;
$data['25.08.24']['low'] = 4;
$data['26.08.24']['open'] = 5;
$data['26.08.24']['close'] = 6;
$data['26.08.24']['high'] = 7;
$data['26.08.24']['low'] = 8;
и все без предупреждений работает
В моем коде получилось
$data[1]['open'] = 1;
$data[2]['close'] = 2;
$data[3]['high'] = 3;
и т.д. т.е. кривой 2-мерный массив.

<?
$data = []; // Инициализация массива
// Корректное добавление подмассивов с ключами
$data[] = ['open' => 1, 'close' => 2,
 'high' => 3, 'low' => 4];
$data[] = ['open' => 5, 'close' => 6, 
'high' => 7, 'low' => 8];

// Цикл для вывода значений 'open'
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['open'] . "<br>"; 
// Теперь ошибок не будет
}
?>

